# How to get text in button centred vertically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a style which specifies that the gravity of the button should be centered vertically:

```
<style name="button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
</style>
```

But for some reason, all the text on my buttons is horizontally centered but vertically it sits very close to the bottom of the button. Am I missing something obscure here?

Comment: try to set gravity just center

Comment: BTW,, `textSize` should be in `sp` and not `dip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align text within the button you need `android:gravity`, for example

```
<Button 
    ...
    android:gravity="center"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    ...>
</Button>
```

**UpDate :** The `Text` have `includeFontPadding` property is `true` which have some pre defined `Padding` so you have to set it to `false` and set `Padding` what you have want.

Comment: Changed it, same problem.

Comment: Perfect, the includeFontPadding made all the difference.

Comment: @user3690202 glad to help you.